# Cant see last element in listview Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview

I have a UI like this:
The ListView still appears, but the last element is not visible unless I scroll down and hold it. Why is that? I want the items to be fully visible when I scroll. I use a Stack because the list is overlaid on top of the image, that's why I did it that way. Help me!
[image]

This code:

```
SafeArea(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      AppImages.backgroundTechnicalSupport,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 20,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: PaddingConstants.h20R,
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  LocaleKeys.technicalSupport_title.tr(),
                                  maxLines: 2,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24.zsp(context),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 280.wh,
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadiusConstants.tl15tr15,
                          color: ThemeHelper.backgroundRealm(context),
                        ),
                        padding: PaddingConstants.h20v10R,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            14.wVerticalSpace,
                            Text(
                              LocaleKeys.technicalSupport_supportType.tr(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.zsp(context),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: ThemeHelper.black(context),
                              ),
                            ),
                            16.wVerticalSpace,
                            Container(
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                maxHeight:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 260.wh,
                              ),
                              child: ListView.separated(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                  return Container(
                                    padding: PaddingConstants.h20v10R,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: ThemeHelper
                                            .borderDateMeetingRoom(context),
                                      ),
                                      borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadiusConstants.c15wr,
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                       
                                        16.wHorizontalSpace,
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: PaddingConstants.v20R,
                                            child: Text(
                                              'Cai dat tai khoan',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                fontSize: 18.zsp(context),
                                                color: ThemeHelper
                                                    .primaryBlueColor(
                                                    context),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        SvgPicture.asset(
                                          AppImages.arrowRight,
                                          colorFilter:
                                          ThemeHelper.primaryBlueColor(
                                              context)
                                              .toSvgColor,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                separatorBuilder: (_, __) =>
                                15.wVerticalSpace,
                                itemCount: 6,
                              )
                            
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

Im not good in english, sorry for this

Comment: can you share issue gif?

Comment: @JeelBhatti https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-cf14bd3edf.gif
u can see the gif, I have to scroll down and hold to see the last item.

Comment: use positioned.fill in ListView.separated. try this if not work then tell me. also wrap ListView.separated with expanded widget

Comment: @JeelBhatti the full code is above (in my post)

Comment: @JeelBhatti when i wrap listview with expanded, it show error: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
when i change Positioned to Positioned.fill it show error: A RenderFlex overflowed by 178 pixels on the bottom.

Comment: can you share github link so better to understand? current i dont't have your text format or padding value so this is not for accurate solution.

Comment: @JeelBhatti, this is my project in my company, but i can share a sample code, are u using skype or something?

Comment: okay i will provide demo code use it and give me up vote if it worked.

Comment: @JeelBhatti where u will demo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is demo code also i am providing dart pad code https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1 so you can checkout if any error or issue in your code then message me if it's work then up vote.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
    //                     Image.asset(
    //                       AppImages.backgroundTechnicalSupport,
    //                       fit: BoxFit.fill,
    //                     ),
                        Positioned(
                          top: 20,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding:EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
    //                             padding: PaddingConstants.h20R,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
    //                                   LocaleKeys.technicalSupport_title.tr(),
                                      "Testing"
    ,                                  maxLines: 2,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 24,//.zsp(context),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned.fill(
                          top: 280,
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
    //                           borderRadius: BorderRadiusConstants.tl15tr15,
    //                           color: ThemeHelper.backgroundRealm(context),
                            ),
    //                         padding: PaddingConstants.h20v10R,
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
    //                             14.wVerticalSpace,
                                Text(
    //                               LocaleKeys.technicalSupport_supportType.tr(),
                                  "Test",
                                  style: TextStyle(
    //                                 fontSize: 20.zsp(context),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    //                                 color: ThemeHelper.black(context),
                                  ),
                                ),
    //                             16.wVerticalSpace,
                                Expanded(
    //                               constraints: BoxConstraints(
    // //                                 maxHeight:
    // //                                     MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 260.wh,
    //                               ),
                                  child: ListView.separated(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                      return Container(
    //                                     padding: PaddingConstants.h20v10R,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          border: Border.all(
    //                                         color: ThemeHelper
    //                                             .borderDateMeetingRoom(context),
                                          ),
    //                                       borderRadius:
    //                                       BorderRadiusConstants.c15wr,
                                        ),
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                           
    //                                         16.wHorizontalSpace,
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: Text(
                                                'Cai dat tai khoan $index',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                  fontSize: 18,//.zsp(context),
    //                                               color: ThemeHelper
    //                                                   .primaryBlueColor(
    //                                                   context),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
    //                                         SvgPicture.asset(
    //                                           AppImages.arrowRight,
    //                                           colorFilter:
    //                                           ThemeHelper.primaryBlueColor(
    //                                               context)
    //                                               .toSvgColor,
    //                                         ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    separatorBuilder: (_, __) =>SizedBox(height:15,),
    //                                 15.wVerticalSpace,
                                    itemCount: 60,
                                  )
                                
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
    )
          );
      }
    }
```

Comment: @huy-nguyen It worked or not?

Comment: sorry, im late. yeah it worked, u save my life, tks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your ListView with padding, and set according to your need.
you can also add this padding in your continer directly.

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            AppImages.backgroundTechnicalSupport,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 20,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: PaddingConstants.h20R,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        LocaleKeys.technicalSupport_title.tr(),
                        maxLines: 2,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24.zsp(context),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 280.wh,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadiusConstants.tl15tr15,
                color: ThemeHelper.backgroundRealm(context),
              ),
              padding: PaddingConstants.h20v10R,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  14.wVerticalSpace,
                  Text(
                    LocaleKeys.technicalSupport_supportType.tr(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.zsp(context),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: ThemeHelper.black(context),
                    ),
                  ),
                  //16.wVerticalSpace,
                  Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 260.wh,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: PaddingConstants.h0v16R, // set according your need 
                        child: ListView.separated(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                            return Container(
                              padding: PaddingConstants.h20v10R,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: ThemeHelper.borderDateMeetingRoom(
                                      context),
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadiusConstants.c15wr,
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  16.wHorizontalSpace,
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: PaddingConstants.v20R,
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Cai dat tai khoan',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          fontSize: 18.zsp(context),
                                          color: ThemeHelper.primaryBlueColor(
                                              context),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SvgPicture.asset(
                                    AppImages.arrowRight,
                                    colorFilter:
                                        ThemeHelper.primaryBlueColor(context)
                                            .toSvgColor,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (_, __) => 15.wVerticalSpace,
                          itemCount: 6,
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: It still didn't load full item

Comment: https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-cf14bd3edf.gif
 u can see the gif, I must have to scroll down and hold to see the last item